# hide div on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

When the user clicks on 'Comment' button.

```
<input id="SubmitCommentsToInvoice" type="button" value="Comments" onclick="ShowCommentBox('<%: item.DBId %>', '<%: item.LabourOrPlant %>', '<%: item.ActivityDescription %>')" />
```

A text area loads, with a submit button.  When the user has finished entering data and they click 'submit' I want the box to disappear.(returning to normal screen viewing)

```
    <div id="dialog" title="Comments"  style="display:none;">   
    <textarea id="BlankBox" type="text" runat="server" rows="7" 
     maxlength="2000" />     
    <input id="SubmitComment" type="button" value="Submit"
                    onclick="SubmitButton()" />  
     </div> 

    function SubmitButton() {
                var commentBoxData = $('#<%=BlankBox.ClientID%>').val();
                WorkItemMgr.CommentBoxForInvoiceUpdates(id, LabouringOrPlanting, commentBoxData, testForSuccess);
            }

            function testForSuccess(CommentSuccessfullyUpdated) 
            {
                if (CommentSuccessfullyUpdated == "TRUE") 
                {
                    //$('#' + IdCommentBox).hide();
                    // $('#<%=BlankBox.ClientID%>').hide(); just hides comment box need to hide entire thing
                    $("#dialog").dialog({ modal: true }).hide();
    //IN HERE I WOULD LIKE TO HIDE THE DIV (MY ATTEMPTS SEEN ABOVE)
                }
                else if (CommentSuccessfullyUpdated == "False") 
                {
                    showLoadingImage.src = "../Images/X.png";
                }
            }
```

My attempts have hidden the textarea, but I want to hide the entire div again and return to normal viewing of the screen (getting rid of the modal:true)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this line is doing what you think it's doing:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({ modal: true }).hide();
```

This tells the dialog plugin to initialize `#dialog` as a new dialog (modal), and then tells jQuery to hide the whole thing.  If `#dialog` is *already* a modal dialog at this point and you just want to hide it, try this:

```
$("#dialog").dialog("close");
```

This tells the dialog plugin to hide (or close) an existing dialog.

In general you want to use a plugin's native functionality instead of trying to apply other functionality to it, where possible.  In this particular case, it's better to tell the jQuery UI Dialog to hide itself rather than try to use jQuery (which has no knowledge of the dialog plugin) to hide the div, since it doesn't know if there's anything "special" about that div (which there is, another plugin is using it... jQuery UI Dialog).

Answer (score 1):

if you use jQuery ui dialog then you should use [close method](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close)

```
$("#dialog").dialog('close');
```

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery:

```
$("#div_id").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery

```
 $('#BlankBox').hide();
```

In javascript

```
document.getElementById("BlankBox").style.display='none';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery UI dialog, try with: `$("#dialog").dialog({ hide: 1 });`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Comments"  style="display:none;">   
  <textarea id="BlankBox" type="text" runat="server" rows="7" maxlength="2000" />     
  <input id="SubmitComment" type="button" value="Submit"/>
</div>
```

jQuery will be:

```
$(function(){
   $('#SubmitComment').click(function(){
      $(this).closest('#dialog').hide();
   });
});
```